# threading in libgdx and general questions to move sprites

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am reassembling my game i wrote for android. It was written with simple canvas to learn the basics. To get it to a higher level i am going to write it with the help of `libgdx`. 
To do so i thought about a `stage` where i add my `Actors` (Monsters, skills if they are active, character and maybe particle) to. I read that this is a good way to assamble a 2D Game.

Some more informations about it. It's a 2D RPG based on an square system. Every step is one move to the next square.(maybe tile based lateron. At the moment the background is a single picture)

In the old version i used threads for every Monster so they can handle and react as they "wish". Is this also possible in libgdx or do i need to handle it in a different way?

If i want to move the Character from one to the next square i had a calculated time where i moved the sprite from one square to the next by changing it's pixelposition. In libgdx i am going to have a camera with the squares as init. So (40f,30f) for example. Does it work to move the character within an `thread` as i did in the old game? So i knew that it does take 500ms from one square to the next so every 50ms the ppuX need to be +0.1f. I also updated the sprite depending on that. So if it moves faster the sprite gets faster changed.

I also programmed the skills in that way. For example a fireball is a picture that gets moved by a thread till it hit something.

See the picture of the "prototype". [image: Picture of the prototype with canvas]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably possible, but assigning a thread per entity is a very bad idea - so bad, in fact, that it has a corresponding TheDailyWTF entry:

http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Sprite_Threading.aspx

Not only are you consuming resources unnecessarily in this approach, you're also endangering your sanity in the long run. I believe the linked entry, along with the comments, exhaustively elaborates on why that is the case.

Generally, libgdx supports the "main-loop" model, via the [`ApplicationListener`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/ApplicationListener.html) class (specifically the [`render()`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/ApplicationListener.html#render%28%29) method). [There is a number of tutorials](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/documentation.html) to get you started, [including one for Android](http://obviam.net/index.php/getting-started-in-android-game-development-with-libgdx-create-a-working-prototype-in-a-day-tutorial-part-1/).

I know the approach may seem more limiting at first, but it allows for much more reliable code.

Comment: i know of that tutorial but i wonder how i get my monsters to calculate the next step if they made their first step. Can i simply run a calculus in that rendering if his move is done? So i always check a boolean "movedone" which get set if hes at the next block. and if movedone i do calculate the next step? Everything in that thread in the `stage.act()` ?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you (if not, please rephrase the answer), but I think your question was about how to get your monsters (entities) "know" that they should move. Well, since you will be running in a single thread, you don't have to have a `moveDone` flag - a monster has either moved, or not, there's no intermediary state. You could e.g. move all your monsters in one block in the `render` method, and then perform additional logic. Does this answer your question?

Comment: More or less. I got a square system and always want them to calculate the next move. So if they are in a square (move done) i want to calculate the best next square to go to. This even with a good KI algorithm later on.

Comment: Well, the biggest initial problem here would be conflict resolution - if two monsters want to move at the same time, which should move first? You could solve it simple looping over your monsters in your `render` method, in a consistent order - what the order is, that depends on your game. After the "move phase" (or before it), you would then have an "effect phase", which would contain the rest of your logic. Note that this will be much easier to wrap your head around with one thread. BTW, AI, Artificial Intelligence, is the "global" term for KI - I only know it because I know German :).

Comment: Haha Thanks for that advice just didnt notice that i really wrote KI instead of AI. And you are right. At the old game i got several problems with synchronizing. Some monsters just loved to walk at the same block every time. (i mean 2 at one block :D)

So thats a good idea to loop them over. (how else) Lets see if i can get that with the movement and checking if move done and calculate the next step and so on.

How about a particle? Can i make it as Actor if i want to add particles at a map for example as spawning fire?

Comment: Yeah, that's one of the typical problems with concurrency in such cases. Do you mean particle effects? Well it's just a graphical effect [just graphical effects](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/ParticleEffect.html) in libgdx, which you can e.g. attach to an actor using the `draw` method - which makes sense, you're not constructing your logic around graphics (the effect spawner) but around your game logic (e.g. a dragon that breathes fire, which would be an Actor).

Comment: Finally, if you have an additional questions, I would recommend you to go over the the libgdx tutorials, documentation, search for relevant questions here, and then **post a new question**. Otherwise, useful stuff that can be used by other people might become lost in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

In LibGdx, the **[Game](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx-users/wiki/ScreenAndGameClasses)** class's **render()** method will be called continuously. In this method you can do 4 things.

1) Process Input 
2) Update sprites/actors 
3) Check collision 
4) render the world

You don't need to create a separate thread for moving game objects.